# Where is the themeMode property in CupertinoApp

Tags: flutter

In MaterialApp I can use `themeMode` to explicitly set the theme of the app.

```dart
themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
```

I couldn't find a similar one in `CupertinoApp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use brightness property in the `CupertinoThemeData` for it.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const CupertinoApp(
      theme: CupertinoThemeData(
         brightness: Brightness.light,
      ),
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
```